# How do I override Firefox keybindings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, key-bindings

I am writing an HTML5 application with some custom keybindings.  I want to use F3 as a keybinding to do some work in my application.  However in Firefox, F3 opens up the search box.  Does anyone know how to override (or remove) default keybindings from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the bindings for the F1-F5 keys cannot be replaced.  I moved to using F8 and everything is working now.  If someone is interested in the code, I can post a snippet (just leave a comment below).